# AndroidR, isDhcpLeaseCacheEnabled always return true. How to disable it?

Tags: java, android

```
    /**
   * check whether or not to support caching the last lease info and INIT-REBOOT state.
   *
   * INIT-REBOOT state is supported on Android R by default if there is no experiment flag set to
   * disable this feature explicitly, meanwhile turning this feature on/off by pushing experiment
   * flag makes it possible to do A/B test and metrics collection on both of Android Q and R, but
   * it's disabled on Android Q by default.
   */

  public boolean isDhcpLeaseCacheEnabled() {
      final boolean defaultEnabled =
              ShimUtils.isReleaseOrDevelopmentApiAbove(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q);
      return mDependencies.isFeatureEnabled(mContext, DHCP_INIT_REBOOT_VERSION, defaultEnabled);
  }
```

I want to turn off this feature , but no way to change it.

Comment: this code has nothing to do with enabling or disabling that functionality. It is just a check whether or not is enabled/disabled.

Comment: yes, but how Can I make this api return false through configuration or other operations?

Comment: by disabling the functionality.

Comment: hi,stultuske, it is mainline at normal android R. so I want to know if there is a configuration method to disable it.

Comment: how can i modified the value about DHCP_INIT_REBOOT_VERSION ?